# How to show specifics data on datatable

Tags: jquery, css, laravel, datatables, laravel-6

i want to ask something...
how to separate specific data on datatables ? filtered by `SKU` number.
I wan to make 2 tables instead SKU Produk

> SKU Code = "11-------" is for **table 1**
> SKU Code = "33-------" is for **table 2**

[Produk-Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Arm17.png)

```php
@extends('layout.master')
@section('title', 'Daftar Produk')
@section('parentPageTitle', 'Produk')
@section('page-style')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/plugins/jquery-datatable/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css')}}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/plugins/sweetalert/sweetalert.css')}}"/>
@stop
@section('content')
@include('sweetalert::alert')

<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="body">
                <div>
                    <a href="{{ route('produk.create')}}" class="btn btn-success btn-round" data-type="confirm"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-account-add"></i>&nbsp;Tambah Produk</a>
                    <a style="margin: 2px;" href="{{ route('produk.index')}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="zmdi zmdi-refresh"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    @if(session()->get('success'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            {{ session()->get('success') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif
                </div>
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover dataTable js-exportable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="align-middle text-center" style="width:5%">#</th>
                            <th class="align-middle text-center" style="width:15%">SKU</th>
                            <th class="align-middle text-center" style="width:28%">Nama Produk</th>
                            <th class="align-middle text-center" style="width:11%">Harga Beli</th>
                            <th class="align-middle text-center" style="width:11%">Harga Jual</th>
                            <th class="align-middle text-center" style="width:15%">Status</th>
                            <th class="align-middle text-center" style="width:15%">Aksi</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @if(!empty($datas) && $datas->count())
                            @foreach($datas as $data)
                            <tr>
                                <td class="align-middle text-center">{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
                                <td class="align-middle text-center">{{$data->sku}}</td>
                                <td class="align-middle">{{$data->p_nama}}</td>
                                {{-- <td class="align-middle">Rp. {{ number_format($data->p_jual,0) }}</td> --}}
                                <td class="align-middle">Rp. {{ number_format($data->p_beli,0) }}</td>
                                <td class="align-middle">Rp. {{ number_format($data->p_harga,0) }}</td>
                                @if($data->status == 'tersedia')
                                <td class="align-middle text-center">
                                    <label class="badge badge-success" ><strong>Tersedia</strong></label>
                                </td>
                                @else
                                <td class="align-middle text-center">
                                    <label class="badge badge-default" ><strong>Tidak Dijual</strong></label>
                                </td>
                                @endif
                                {{-- <td class="align-middle text-center">{{$data->status}}</td> --}}
                                <td class="align-middle text-center">
                                    {{-- <a href="{{ route('produk.show',$data->id)}}" title="Lihat" class="btn btn-primary btn-icon btn-icon-mini btn-round"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-eye"></i> </a>&nbsp; --}}
                                    <button title="Lihat" class="btn btn-primary btn-icon btn-icon-mini btn-round" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lihat"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-eye"></i> </button>&nbsp;
                                    <a href="{{ route('produk.edit', $data->id)}}" title="Ubah" class="btn btn-warning btn-icon btn-icon-mini btn-round"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-edit"></i></span></a>&nbsp;
                                    <a href="{{ route('produk.delete', $data->id)}}" title="Hapus" class="btn btn-danger btn-icon btn-icon-mini btn-round" data-type="success"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete"></i></span></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        @else
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="8">Data tidak ditemukan! Silahkan buat data Produk terlebih dahulu.</td>
                            </tr>
                        @endif
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                {{-- {!! $datas->links() !!} --}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="body">
                <div>
                    <a href="{{ route('produk.create')}}" class="btn btn-success btn-round" data-type="confirm"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-account-add"></i>&nbsp;Tambah Produk</a>
                    <a style="margin: 2px;" href="{{ route('produk.index')}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="zmdi zmdi-refresh"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    @if(session()->get('success'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            {{ session()->get('success') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif
                </div>
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover dataTable js-exportable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="align-middle text-center" style="width:5%">#</th>
                            <th class="align-middle text-center" style="width:15%">SKU</th>
                            <th class="align-middle text-center" style="width:28%">Nama Produk Kopi</th>
                            <th class="align-middle text-center" style="width:11%">Harga Beli</th>
                            <th class="align-middle text-center" style="width:11%">Harga Jual</th>
                            <th class="align-middle text-center" style="width:15%">Status</th>
                            <th class="align-middle text-center" style="width:15%">Aksi</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @if(!empty($datas) && $datas->count())
                            @foreach($datas as $data)
                            <tr>
                                <td class="align-middle text-center">{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
                                <td class="align-middle text-center">{{$data->sku}}</td>
                                <td class="align-middle">{{$data->p_nama}}</td>
                                {{-- <td class="align-middle">Rp. {{ number_format($data->p_jual,0) }}</td> --}}
                                <td class="align-middle">Rp. {{ number_format($data->p_beli,0) }}</td>
                                <td class="align-middle">Rp. {{ number_format($data->p_harga,0) }}</td>
                                @if($data->status == 'tersedia')
                                <td class="align-middle text-center">
                                    <label class="badge badge-success" ><strong>Tersedia</strong></label>
                                </td>
                                @else
                                <td class="align-middle text-center">
                                    <label class="badge badge-default" ><strong>Tidak Dijual</strong></label>
                                </td>
                                @endif
                                {{-- <td class="align-middle text-center">{{$data->status}}</td> --}}
                                <td class="align-middle text-center">
                                    {{-- <a href="{{ route('produk.show',$data->id)}}" title="Lihat" class="btn btn-primary btn-icon btn-icon-mini btn-round"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-eye"></i> </a>&nbsp; --}}
                                    <button title="Lihat" class="btn btn-primary btn-icon btn-icon-mini btn-round" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lihat"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-eye"></i> </button>&nbsp;
                                    <a href="{{ route('produk.edit', $data->id)}}" title="Ubah" class="btn btn-warning btn-icon btn-icon-mini btn-round"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-edit"></i></span></a>&nbsp;
                                    <a href="{{ route('produk.delete', $data->id)}}" title="Hapus" class="btn btn-danger btn-icon btn-icon-mini btn-round" data-type="success"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete"></i></span></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        @else
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="8">Data tidak ditemukan! Silahkan buat data Produk terlebih dahulu.</td>
                            </tr>
                        @endif
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                {{-- {!! $datas->links() !!} --}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Lihat modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="lihat" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h2 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Detail Produk</h2>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row clearfix">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="body">
                                @if ($errors->any())
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                    <ul>
                                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <br />
                                @endif
                                <table class="table table-hover dataTable js-exportable">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr height="40px">
                                            <th class="align-middle" style="width:18%"><b>Barcode</b></th>
                                            <td class="align-middle" style="width:2%">:</td>
                                            <td class="align-middle" style="width:28%">
                                                <div class="barcode align-middle">
                                                    {!! DNS1D::getBarcodeHTML($data->sku, "C128",2.2,60) !!}
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <th class="align-middle" style="width:18%"><b>QR Code</b></th>
                                            <td class="align-middle" style="width:2%">:</td>
                                            <td class="align-middle">
                                                <div class="barcode" rowspan="2">
                                                    {!! QrCode::size(100)->generate($data->sku); !!}
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr height="60px">
                                            <th class="align-middle" style="width:18%"><b>Nama Produk</b></th>
                                            <td class="align-middle" style="width:2%">:</td>
                                            <td class="align-middle" style="width:25%">{{ $data->p_nama }}</td>
                                            <th class="align-middle" style="width:18%"></th>
                                            <td class="align-middle" style="width:2%"></td>
                                            <td class="align-middle" style="width:25%"></td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr height="60px">
                                            <th class="align-middle" style="width:18%"><b>Harga Beli</b></th>
                                            <td class="align-middle" style="width:2%">:</td>
                                            <td class="align-middle text-danger"><strong>Rp. {{ number_format($data->p_beli,0) }}</strong> ,-</td>
                                            <th class="align-middle" style="width:18%"><b>Harga Jual</b></th>
                                            <td class="align-middle" style="width:2%">:</td>
                                            <td class="align-middle text-danger"><strong>Rp. {{ number_format($data->p_harga,0) }}</strong> ,-</td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr height="60px">
                                            <th class="align-middle" style="width:18%"><b>Dibuat pada</b></th>
                                            <td class="align-middle" style="width:2%">:</td>
                                            <td class="align-middle" style="width:25%">{{ $data->created_at->isoFormat('dddd, D MMMM Y') }}</td>
                                            <th class="align-middle" style="width:18%"><b>Diupdate pada</b></th>
                                            <td class="align-middle" style="width:2%">:</td>
                                            <td class="align-middle">{{ $data->updated_at->diffForHumans() }}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="{{ route('produk.index')}}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="zmdi zmdi-undo"></i>&nbsp;Simpan Perubahan</a>&nbsp;
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@stop
@section('page-script')
<script src="{{asset('assets/bundles/datatablescripts.bundle.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/plugins/jquery-datatable/buttons/dataTables.buttons.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/plugins/jquery-datatable/buttons/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/plugins/jquery-datatable/buttons/buttons.colVis.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/plugins/jquery-datatable/buttons/buttons.flash.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/plugins/jquery-datatable/buttons/buttons.html5.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/plugins/jquery-datatable/buttons/buttons.print.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/js/pages/tables/jquery-datatable.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/plugins/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/js/pages/ui/sweetalert.js')}}"></script>
@stop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two table for SKU code 11 and SKU code 33. you need to filter with  SKU code

```
@foreach($datas as $data)
@if(str_starts_with($data->sku, '11'))
<tr>
 <td>...</td>
</tr>
@endif
@endforeach
```